# Print the number of unique vowels in a string, Java

Tags: java, string

I need to find the number of distinct vowels. I came up with the code below but it can't make distinction between same vowels:

```
public static int count_Vowels(String str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i'
                || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: When you say  "unique", do you  mean it only counts a specific vowel once? Give an example input and output.

Comment: I sometimes give this task on interviews. And **NOT A SINGLE SOUL** ever asked "Vowels in which language?"

Comment: Yes various occurrences of same vowel shouldn't count

Comment: Give an example input and the desired output.

Comment: input"AAAEEEE" output "2"

Comment: Is this for an assignment?

Comment: It works absolutely fine for me,  input "AAAEEEE" gives me 7, which I'd expect from the name of the method

Comment: @Fubar:  If you're looking for "distinct" vowels, you should get two since only "A" and "E" appear.

Comment: @Makoto absolutely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start with five variables (one for each vowel) set to `0`, iterate the characters in the input and set the corresponding variable to `1` if I find a match, and simply return the accumulated value of said variables. Like,

```
public static int count_Vowels(String str) {
    int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0;
    for (char ch : str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == 'a') {
            a = 1;
        } else if (ch == 'e') {
            e = 1;
        } else if (ch == 'i') {
            i = 1;
        } else if (ch == 'o') {
            o = 1;
        } else if (ch == 'u') {
            u = 1;
        }
    }
    return a + e + i + o + u;
}
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch , your solution is, of course, a very efficient one. I'm just wondering - in the case of longer strings - which approach is considered as a more efficient: 1) in your for loop, after last `else-if` adding a bit of code that checks if `a+e+i+o+u` is already equal to 5 (note that it is being executed in each loop) and if it is, breaking the loop and immediate returning this sum? 2) looping whole string without additional code that I mentioned, exactly as you did in your example (additional code is not added, but you need to loop over entire string).

Comment: I considered that; this solution is `O(n)` - adding a short-circuit return optimization would still leave it as O(n). I worry about premature optimization too, we want the algorithm to be clear in the answer - optimizing it might distract from that (which is why I ultimately decided not to here).

Comment: Thank you for providing an explanation, as in such cases I always think if I should include such an additional part that would quit loop if necessary - it seems like it's better not to include too much of that to avoid making too much mess in code. Maybe if OP would ask in question that he looks for the possibly most efficient way of solving the problem, it would be worth considering to add further improvements. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for commenting this @PrzemysławMoskal it hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: Hey @Fubar - What hadn't occur to you?

Comment: adding the check to see whether the sum was equal to 5 @PrzemysławMoskal It's just an optimisation that I didn't think of

Comment: @Fubar Ok, I got it now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Set data structure and instead of incrementing the counter just add vowels to the set. At the end you can return just the size of the set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are not counting the distinct vowels, but all the vowels in the string. A Java-8 way to this:

```
public static int countDistinctVowels(String str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    int count = (int) str.chars()                     // get IntStream of chars
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)                  // cast to char
            .filter(c -> "aeiou".indexOf(c) > -1)     // remove all non-vowels
            .distinct()                               // keep the distinct values
            .count();                                 // count the values

    return count;
}
```

Also use proper Java naming conventions: `countDistinctVowels`, no `count_Distinct_Vowels`.

Comment: Downvoter please explain the reason of the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

there's definitely an issue here with this counting. at the very least. you should rethink this:

```
if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i'
                || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u')

            count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `contains`

```
public static int count_Vowels(String str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    int count = 0;
    count += string.contains("a") ? 1 : 0;
    count += string.contains("e") ? 1 : 0;
    count += string.contains("i") ? 1 : 0;
    count += string.contains("o") ? 1 : 0;
    count += string.contains("u") ? 1 : 0;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this answer was downvoted. Is also a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made explanations in the comments to the code:

```
public static int count_Vowels(String str) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        Set<Character> setOfUsedChars = new HashSet<>(); // Here you store used vowels
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i'
                    || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u') { // if currently checked character is vowel...
                setOfUsedChars.add(str.charAt(i)); // add this vowel to setOfUsedChars
            }
        }
        return setOfUsedChars.size(); // size of this sets is a number of vowels present in input String
}
```

Comment: I'm waiting for the same in my answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza Thank you for your suggestion. I thought that checking presence of that vowel in set and eventual skipping loop in case of presence of that vowel in set is faster than execution of code adding the same vowel to the set on and on. I used a rollback option to edit this answer to its previous state. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void vow(String input){          
    String output=input.toLowerCase();
    int flaga=0,flage=0,flagi=0,flago=0,flagu=0;
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++) {
        if((output.charAt(i))=='a' && flaga==0) {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i)+" ");
            flaga++;
        }
        if(output.charAt(i)=='e' && flage==0) {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i)+" ");
            flage++;
        }
        if(output.charAt(i)=='i' && flagi==0) {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i)+" ");
            flagi++;
        }
        if(output.charAt(i)=='o' && flago==0) {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i)+" ");
            flago++;
        }
        if(output.charAt(i)=='u' && flagu==0) {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i)+" ");
            flagu++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, while this may be the correct answer, you should be leaving a little insight/ explanation of what you have done here to make it a quality answer which will help others understand the root cause of problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String sentence;
    int v=0,c=0,ws=0;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    sentence = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();
    sentence.toLowerCase();
    String res="";
    for(int i=0;i<sentence.length();i++) {

        if(sentence.charAt(i)=='a'||sentence.charAt(i)=='e'||sentence.charAt(i)=='i'||sentence.charAt(i)=='o'||sentence.charAt(i)=='u') {
        if(res.indexOf(sentence.charAt(i))<0) {
            res+=sentence.charAt(i);
        v++;
        }//System.out.println(res.indexOf(sentence.charAt(i)));
            }
        else if(sentence.charAt(i)==' ')
            ws++;
        else c++;
    }
    System.out.println(res);
    System.out.println("no of vowels: "+v+"\n"+"no of consonants: "+c+"\n"+"no of 
   white spaces: "+ws);
}
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Method to Find Count of Distinct vowels.

```
public static int count_Vowels(String str) {
    char[] c = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int Counter=0;
     String NewString="";
     for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
         String tempString="";
         tempString+=c[i];
         if(!NewString.contains(tempString) && (c[i]=='a'||c[i]=='e'||c[i]=='i'||c[i]=='o'||c[i]=='u')){
             Counter++;
             NewString+=c[i];
         }
     }
    return Counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solve for this problem without using objects. It's a crude but great solve for beginners who encounter this problem with limited js experience.

How to count unique vowels is a string;

```
function hasUniqueFourVowels(str){
let va = 0
let ve = 0  
let vi = 0
let vo = 0
let vu = 0
let sum = 0
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
 let char = str[i];
   if(char === "i"){
    vi = 1
  }
    if(char === "e"){
    ve = 1
  }
   if(char === "a"){
    va = 1
  }
  if(char === "o"){
   vo = 1
   }
  if(char === "u"){
  vu = 1
  }
  sum = va + vi + vo + ve + vu
  if (sum >= 4){
   return true
   }
 }
   return false

 }
```

Comment: Why do you answer with non-java code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Test
public void numfindVoweles(){
    String s="aeiouaedtesssiou";
    char a[]=s.toCharArray();
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hp= new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(char ch:a){
        if(hp.containsKey(ch) && (ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u')){
           hp.put(ch,hp.get(ch)+1);
       }
        else if(ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u'){
            hp.put(ch,1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hp);

}
```

Comment: we can get the count of each vowels using hashmap with less code. hope it will be usefule